# Validation rule for a days time lapse in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I have a form with two date fields, these fields define a time period, characterized by a starting date and an ending date, instead of forcing the user to type a date, I´m using a javascript date selector for those dates, I have validation rules for each field through callbacks, like this:

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fechainicio', 'Fecha de Inicio', 'required|callback_startDate_valid');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fechafin', 'Fecha de Fin', 'required|callback_endDate_valid');
```

The rules work Ok, individually, no problem! but as these fields define a (days) time period, I need the starting date to be older than the ending date, this would be my 3rd validation rule, but, how do I do this if the date fields are separate? If I use the post values, they are only known after dates have been chosen, this causes an initial error (unknown array index) because the fields are empty when you load the form intially, any idea? thanx i.a.

Comment: if you use ci 3 doc says `If you need to receive an extra parameter in your callback method, just add it normally after the method name between square brackets, as in: “callback_foo**[bar]**”, then it will be passed as the second argument of your callback method.`

Answer (score 2):

you can take value of start date inside your endDate function.

```
function endDate_valid($endDate)
{
  $startDate = $this->input->post('fechainicio');

  if($startDate > $endDate){
    $this->form_validation->set_message('endDate_valid','End Date must be greater than start date');
    return FALSE;
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by testing the dates before they reach the dates, this way:

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])){
        $post_data = array();
        if( $this->input->post() ){
            $post_data = $this->input->post();
            if( $post_data['fechainicio'] < $post_data['fechafin'] ){
                $data['fechaUno'] = $post_data['fechainicio'];
                $data['fechaDos'] = $post_data['fechafin'];
            }else{
                echo "There´s an error in dates order.";
            }
        }
    }
```

though I see some redundance in `isset($_POST['save'])` and the `if( $this->input->post() )` condition, anyway it worked, I just tried @jagad89 tip and works great!, thanx!!

Comment: Why you did `if( $this->input->post() )`??

Comment: Because I wanted to check if something was posted, but as I said, it´s redundant after `if (isset($_POST['save']))`.

Comment: I would like to see your controller function. i think if you doing `if($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE)` ( and you must have did that because you using form validation) some where in your function, then you don't need that. Second thing is that stick to codeignitor. Don't use `$_POST` like core global variables because `$this->input->post('fieldname')` comes with security checks.

Comment: @jagad89 Hi, this is the controller function that is taking care of the form:    public function cifrasSemana(){
  $data = array();

  $this->load->helper('url');
  $this->load->helper('form');
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('fechainicio', 'Fecha de Inicio', 'required|callback_startDate_valid');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('fechafin', 'Fecha de Fin', 'required|callback_endDate_valid');

  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
   $this->load->view('reporteenvios_view');
  }else{
   $this->load->view('formsuccess');
  }
 }

Comment: Kind of troubly to see because of format, but that´s all what comments allow, sorry (for this and the lateness) :S

Comment: Not issue friend. Good. Your controller is clean.